# Ios-App get Data from Liferay DB

Tags: php, mysql, ios, liferay

i got a little problem with getting data from my liferay DB. I wrote a php-script to get data from a mysql-server. Now im trying to get data from my liferay table called "blogsentry". Her is what is in the database:
[image: data in DB]

and now i try to get the data by my script which looks like this:

```
    $DB_HostName = "localhost";
$DB_Name = "lportal";
$DB_User = "root";
$DB_Pass = "8PeyJlhzRTplFCoMhf5l";
$DB_Table = "blogsentry";

$con = mysql_connect($DB_HostName,$DB_User,$DB_Pass) or die(mysql_error()); 
mysql_select_db($DB_Name,$con) or die(mysql_error()); 

$sql = "SELECT * FROM lportal.blogsentry";
$res = mysql_query($sql,$con) or die(mysql_error());

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($res, MYSQL_NUM)) {
printf("ID: %s  Name: %s", $row[0], $row[1]);
```

}

```
mysql_close($con);
if ($res) {
    echo "success";
    echo mysql_result($res,0);
}else{
    echo "faild";
}// end else
```

thats the result of the query:

```
ID: 67162b39-ba88-4b8a-ba31-cd0e1c20a2ec Name: 11477ID: 55a8d88b-9242-47a0-bb63-87a0e5ac18dc Name: 11487success67162b39-ba88-4b8a-ba31-cd0e1c20a2ec
```

So, does anybody know what I#m doing wrong?? Why don't I get the content for example???

Answer (score 0):

First column in BlogsEntry table is `uuid_`, so start reading from the second column  which is `entryId`. Also there is no "name", there is a "title" instead.

You can do this way:

```
$sql = "SELECT entryId, title FROM lportal.blogsentry";
```